# Gratis issue tracker which logs edits

Tags: github, issue-tracker

Need something **simple and straightforward** like Github Issues which people can use to write entries and comments filed under your *repo*/*project*. Total budget:
$0.00/decade; nonantisocial ads are a-ok.

I do not require zero account walls (eg Wikipedia), but the account wall must have **no friction** (basically like Github, where I don't have to approve their account, plus they can reuse that account for other purposes).

Also, if not already clear, I mustn't have access to the server's database. You can't edit the dates of posts nor claim that a user has written `foobar` when he hasn't. (basically, like Github)

Caveat: content must be:

1. editable, and
2. edits must be logged.

( * I'm writing this question because Github has no setting to prevent people from removing the legitimate content that has already been posted hours/days ago, thus I can't use Github Issues. )